# Getting subpage of subpage - Custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, wp-list-pages

I have one page with custom posts. They are shown in one page with a list, you can choose one page and when you get to that page I need to show subpages of that page.

Here is so far ive made it, its the first page with the custom posts:

```
  <select name="select_page" id="select_page" class="select_page" data-mini="true" data-theme="c">

    <?php
        $pageId = 5;
        $subpages = get_pages( array(
        'child_of' => $pageId,
        'sort_order' => 'asc',
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order') );
    ?>        

    <?php if($post->post_parent) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo get_page_link($pageId) ?>" >Startpage</option>
    <?php } else {?>
    <option value="<?php echo get_page_link($pageId) ?>" selected="selected">Startpage</option>
    <?php } ?>
```

That was for the list, I need to show subpages of that subpages and show it in the list also.

```
   <?php                                   
    foreach($subpages as $page) { $i++;
    $pages[] += $page->ID;      
    ?>
    <?php if($page->post_title == get_the_title()) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $i.'. '.$page->post_title ?></option>
    <?php } else {?>
    <option value="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>"><?php echo $i.'. '.$page->post_title ?></option>  <?php } ?>
    <?php }?> 

    </select>
```

My question is:

**How can I show subpages of that subpage ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
$subpages = get_pages( array(
'child_of' => $pageId,
'sort_order' => 'asc',
'sort_column' => 'menu_order') );
```

'child_of' parameter also queries for the grandchildren along with children. Use the 'parent' parameter instead which will only query for the direct children. Once this is done, you'll use the same code in your foreach again

```
foreach($subpages as $page) {
    $subsubpages = get_pages( array(
    'parent' => $page->ID,
    'sort_order' => 'asc',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order') );

    // use $subsubpages along with $page here
}
```

If you want to go even lower in levels, you will probably want to implement this logic in the form of a recursive function

Comment: Sorry i didnt really get you there ? Should i do that in the same template or new one ?

Comment: in the same template. The first one is copied from your code, replace `child_of` with `parent` there. The second one should go inside your `foreach` loop